# In which case does sendto() on UDP socket return 0?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp, sendto

Is there a case, when calling of sendto() on UDP socket returns 0 and if yes, what does it mean? Manual only says, that on error it's -1, otherwise it's number of bytes sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `send()`/`sendto()` a zero-byte message on a domain datagram or UDP socket, in which case a returned length of 0 bytes is correct. If you are seeing this unexpectedly, verify your `len` parameter in your `sendto(int fd, void const *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct const *dest, sockles_t addrlen)` call.